# JSONDecodeError: using googletrans module

Tags: python, json, google-translation-api, googletrans

I'm trying to translate 100,000 English words to Korean by using 'googletrans' module. But after some iteration, it raises

> 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'.

I tried to figure it out, but solutions on the web didn't work for me.
**What I've tried is**

1. Re-initializing Translator() every iteration,
2. Time-sleep(.4) every iteration.

The most weird part is that it happens randomly. Sometimes it raises after a few hundreds iteration, sometimes after a few iteration.

I checked manual of this module and the only limit I could find was that it only limits the length of the word. However, all words that I'm trying to translate are just literally words, not phrase or sentences.

```
key_list = list(senticnet.keys())
for key in key_list:
  translator = Translator()
  time.sleep(.4)
  print(translator.translate(key, dest='ko'))
```

In the above code, senticnet is a dictionary variable. It looks like

```
senticnet['abusive_conduct'] = ['0', '0', '0.853', '-0.84', '#anger', '#disgust', 'negative', '-0.84', 'flagrant', 'cry', 'glaring', 'gross', 'rank']
senticnet['abusive_father'] = ['0', '0', '0.821', '-0.95', '#anger', '#disgust', 'negative', '-0.88', 'student', 'serious_student', 'addiction', 'graduate_student', 'hard_worker']
```

Here is the error message

```
/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/py-googletrans/googletrans/client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src)
170 
171         origin = text
--> 172         data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
173 
174         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/py-googletrans/googletrans/client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src)
 79         r = self.session.get(url, params=params)
 80 
---> 81         data = utils.format_json(r.text)
 82         return data
 83 

/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/py-googletrans/googletrans/utils.py in format_json(original)
 60         converted = json.loads(original)
 61     except ValueError:
---> 62         converted = legacy_format_json(original)
 63 
 64     return converted

/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/py-googletrans/googletrans/utils.py in legacy_format_json(original)
 52             text = text[:p] + states[j][1] + text[nxt:]
 53 
---> 54     converted = json.loads(text)
 55     return converted
 56 

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
355     if cls is None:
356         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
337 
338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
340         end = _w(s, end).end()
341         if end != len(s):

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: I checked manual of this module and the only limit I could find was that it only limits the length of the word.

---

Ther are a few other limits!

> From [Googletrans 2.3.0 documentation](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
>
> **Note on library usage**
>
> - Due to limitations of the web version of google translate, this API **does not guarantee that the library would work properly at all times**. (so please use this library if you don’t care about stability.)
> - If you want to use a stable API, I highly recommend you to use Google’s official translate API.
> - If you get HTTP 5xx error or errors like #6, it’s probably because Google has banned your client IP address.

Comment: Thank you, I think it is the problem of the module stability. I have to find another module ( or official API ) :(

Answer (score 0):

The error is misleading, it happens because you get rejected by google due to numerous requests. I could solve this problem in two different ways:

1. Use a VPN and change your IP. It will work again.
2. Go to google and search for something. You will receive a message and a reCAPTCHA to solve. After you do this, it will work again for some time.